# Terminating an L2VPN on JunOS router

Tags: juniper-junos, mpls, juniper-mx, l2vpn

I am trying to terminate an L2VPN on an MX480 but it's not working...

Topology: 7206 trunk vlanid 555 > MX80> MPLS CLOUD > MX480.

7206 (192.168.254.2)  not pinging lt-interface on MX480 (192.168.254.1)

MX480 config:

```
PE_MX80> show configuration routing-instances
L2VPN_LT {
    instance-type l2vpn;
    interface ge-1/0/9.555;
    route-distinguisher 172.16.16.7:555;
    vrf-target target:65000:555;
    protocols {
        l2vpn {
            encapsulation-type ethernet-vlan;
            interface ge-1/0/9.555;
            site TEST {
                site-identifier 101;
                interface ge-1/0/9.555 {
                    remote-site-id 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


PE_MX80> show configuration interfaces ge-1/0/9.555
encapsulation vlan-ccc;
vlan-id 555;

PE_MX80>


PE_MX80> show l2vpn connections instance L2VPN_LT
Layer-2 VPN connections:

Legend for connection status (St)
EI -- encapsulation invalid      NC -- interface encapsulation not CCC/TCC/VPLS
EM -- encapsulation mismatch     WE -- interface and instance encaps not same
VC-Dn -- Virtual circuit down    NP -- interface hardware not present
CM -- control-word mismatch      -> -- only outbound connection is up
CN -- circuit not provisioned    <- -- only inbound connection is up
OR -- out of range               Up -- operational
OL -- no outgoing label          Dn -- down
LD -- local site signaled down   CF -- call admission control failure
RD -- remote site signaled down  SC -- local and remote site ID collision
LN -- local site not designated  LM -- local site ID not minimum designated
RN -- remote site not designated RM -- remote site ID not minimum designated
XX -- unknown connection status  IL -- no incoming label
MM -- MTU mismatch               MI -- Mesh-Group ID not available
BK -- Backup connection          ST -- Standby connection
PF -- Profile parse failure      PB -- Profile busy
RS -- remote site standby        SN -- Static Neighbor
LB -- Local site not best-site   RB -- Remote site not best-site
VM -- VLAN ID mismatch

Legend for interface status
Up -- operational
Dn -- down

Instance: L2VPN_LT
  Local site: TEST (101)
    connection-site           Type  St     Time last up          # Up trans
    100                       rmt   Up     Mar 25 16:38:52 2014           1
      Remote PE: 172.16.16.2, Negotiated control-word: Yes (Null)
      Incoming label: 800007, Outgoing label: 800022
      Local interface: ge-1/0/9.555, Status: Up, Encapsulation: VLAN

PE_MX80>









P_480> show configuration routing-instances L2VPN_LT 
instance-type l2vpn;
interface lt-1/1/0.1;
route-distinguisher 172.16.16.2:555;
vrf-target target:65000:555;
protocols {
    l2vpn {
        encapsulation-type ethernet-vlan;
        interface lt-1/1/0.1;
        site TEST {
            site-identifier 100;
            interface lt-1/1/0.1 {
                remote-site-id 101;
            }
        }
    }
}

P_480> show configuration interfaces lt-1/1/0 
unit 1 {
    encapsulation vlan-ccc;
    vlan-id 555;
    peer-unit 2;
    family ccc;
}
unit 2 {
    encapsulation vlan;
    vlan-id 555;
    peer-unit 1;
    family inet {
        address 192.168.254.1/30;
    }
}


P_480> show configuration chassis 
aggregated-devices {
    ethernet {
        device-count 5;
    }
}
fpc 1 {
    pic 1 {
        tunnel-services;
    }
    sampling-instance IPFIX_TEST;
}
network-services enhanced-ip;

P_480> 
P_480> show l2vpn connections instance L2VPN_LT 
Layer-2 VPN connections:

Legend for connection status (St)   
EI -- encapsulation invalid      NC -- interface encapsulation not CCC/TCC/VPLS
EM -- encapsulation mismatch     WE -- interface and instance encaps not same
VC-Dn -- Virtual circuit down    NP -- interface hardware not present 
CM -- control-word mismatch      -> -- only outbound connection is up
CN -- circuit not provisioned    <- -- only inbound connection is up
OR -- out of range               Up -- operational
OL -- no outgoing label          Dn -- down                      
LD -- local site signaled down   CF -- call admission control failure      
RD -- remote site signaled down  SC -- local and remote site ID collision
LN -- local site not designated  LM -- local site ID not minimum designated
RN -- remote site not designated RM -- remote site ID not minimum designated
XX -- unknown connection status  IL -- no incoming label
MM -- MTU mismatch               MI -- Mesh-Group ID not available
BK -- Backup connection          ST -- Standby connection
PF -- Profile parse failure      PB -- Profile busy
RS -- remote site standby        SN -- Static Neighbor
LB -- Local site not best-site   RB -- Remote site not best-site
VM -- VLAN ID mismatch

Legend for interface status 
Up -- operational           
Dn -- down

Instance: L2VPN_LT
  Local site: TEST (100)
    connection-site           Type  St     Time last up          # Up trans
    101                       rmt   Up     Mar 25 16:39:24 2015           1
      Remote PE: 172.16.16.7, Negotiated control-word: Yes (Null)
      Incoming label: 800022, Outgoing label: 800007
      Local interface: lt-1/1/0.1, Status: Up, Encapsulation: VLAN

P_480>
```

add info INF and BGP

```
MX80_PE> show configuration protocols bgp
group MPLS-VPN {
    type internal;
    family inet {
        unicast;
    }
    family inet-vpn {
        unicast;
    }
    family l2vpn {
        signaling;
    }
    neighbor 172.16.16.6 {
        local-address 172.16.16.7;
        export NHS;
    }
    neighbor 172.16.16.2 {
        local-address 172.16.16.7;
        export NHS;
    }
}




MX480> show configuration protocols bgp group MPLS-VPN 
type internal;
local-address 172.16.16.2;
family inet {
    unicast {
        rib-group AGGREGATE_TO_NAT_TABLE;
    }
    multicast;
}
family inet-vpn {
    unicast;
}
family l2vpn {
    signaling;
}
......................
neighbor 172.16.16.7 {
    description MX80_Mitishi;
    export EXPORT_TO_PE;
}


MX480> 


interface:

MX480> show configuration interfaces lt-1/1/0 
unit 1 {
    encapsulation vlan-ccc;
    vlan-id 555;
    peer-unit 2;
    family ccc;
}
unit 2 {
    encapsulation vlan;
    vlan-id 555;
    peer-unit 1;
    family inet {
        address 192.168.254.1/30;
    }
}

=============================

7206 interface facing to MX80

interface GigabitEthernet0/1.555
 description test l2vpn
 encapsulation dot1Q 555
 ip address 192.168.254.2 255.255.255.252
 ip flow ingress
 ip flow egress

!
```

Comment: Can you please share your BGP configuration for the corresponding neighbor, and the configuration for the interfaces in the l2vpn (on both devices)

Comment: i add info about BGP and Interface

Comment: Have you checked re filters on MX480 are not blocking ICMP? Do you have ARP entries on the boxes for the IPs?

Comment: ICMP not blocked. RE filter blocks only SNMP, SSH...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to add `family ccc` to the interface on the PE_MX80.

```
set interfaces ge-1/0/9 unit 555 family ccc
```